# Will I still get experience for a custom campaign?

Tags: invisible-inc

I would like to try running a campaign where the alarm level doesn't passively increase, so I can try a true stealth run, but I'm at a point in the game where I need to be gaining experience. If I turn off the passive alarm increase, making it a custom game, will I still gain experience?

Comment: What do you mean by gaining experience? All I remember is getting credits to buy upgrades for the agents.

Comment: When you finish a campaign, either by beating the final level or by losing your agency, you gain experience based on the number and difficulty of levels completed. This experience unlocks more starting agents and programs.

Comment: I haven't seen anything that will completely neglect the experience if you play a custom campaign. However, I only had a look at the `death_dialog.lua`. By the way, I strongly discourage you to look at the `.lua` files if you don't want to get spoilered. I found a cheat menu, profiler, debugger, the achievement functions, several hidden strings and other stuff.

Answer (score 3):

I've completed two campaigns, one on a "classic" difficulty and a second run on a "custom" one, and I've gained experience on both runs.

My guess would be what you activate/deactivate/change alters an EXP modifier maybe :)